# finding indices of min or max calculated in a range of an array or matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, indexing

If I have a matrix

`A=rand(50,4);`

and a matrix of range values like

```
range=[1 10 15 30 45 50];
```

and i want to calculate minimum value and its index in all A columns over the range matrix. for example

```
for i=1 :numel(range)-1
[value index]= find(min(A(range(i):range(i+1),[],1)

if i>1
            index=index+ range(i)+1;       % indx# was calculated onlyin a 
                                              % range of array and not for 
                                             %whole array.Updated here
 end

B_ind(i,:)=index;
B_val(i,:)=value;
end
```

How can I get indices of `min(A)` for `range(i:i+1)` without using a loop approach?

Simply put, matrix 'B' should be like

```
B(1,column 1:4)=index of min(A (1:10))   in every column

B(2,column 1:4)=index of min(A (11:15))  in every column

B(3,column 1:4)=index of min(A (16:30))  in every column
```

and so on...

My question is how to do it without a 'for loop'?

Comment: You need to do `index=index+range(i)-1;`, not +1.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the loop? Is this a bottleneck in your code? I think your approach is perfectly fine!

Comment: yes @CrisLuengo you are right. thank you for pointing out the mistake. i agree. I want to follow a vectorized approach as loop takes much more time. in reality my data is pretty big.

Comment: Loops are no longer slow in MATLAB. Some vectorized code is still faster than the corresponding loops, but they are no longer 100x or 1000x faster like in the old days, but rather 2x. A lot of vectorized code nowadays is actually slower, if the vectorization requires large intermediate matrices or complex indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be:

```
% generate example data set
A=rand(50,4);
range=[1 10 15 30 45 50];

% generate indexes of interest
tmp_idx= arrayfun(@colon,range(1:end-1),range(2:end),'un',0);
% calculate the min function over the indexes
[min_value,min_idx]=cellfun(@(x) min(A(x,:)), tmp_idx, 'UniformOutput', false);
% get matrix B (with the offset of ranges)
B=cell2mat(min_idx')+(range(1:end-1)+1)';
B(1,:)=B(1,:)-2;
```

Comment: Nice! But I t won’t be any faster, because `cellfun` and `arrayfun` are implemented as simple loops.